# How to change Homebrew's prefix?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm using MACOS M1, and started to install brew under ARM. Then at the other day, I installed some formula under x86.

When I run a command
`brew doctor`
And I got this message

```
Some of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default
prefix (/usr/local).
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
unsupported configuration.
```

How to change the prefix to /usr/local/?

When I run `which -a brew` I got this result

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn’t one of them a symlink?

Comment: no, I didn't use symlink. both are brew that installed in different architecture. one is on ARM, one is under Rosetta 2 (x86).

Comment: So I am guessing `/usr/local` Is Rosetta (amd64)?  This is a new development for homebrew to use separate dir structures for mac-arm and amd64...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I did not installed the homebrew from the local path on my terminal.

I just uninstalled the homebrew, installed it again (from the local path this time) and it is fine now.

To uninstall Homebrew, run the [uninstall script from the HomeBrew/install repository.](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew)